# JavaFX Spanning Columns with TextArea

Tags: java

I have a simple JavaFX application that has several textfields and 1 textarea in a gridpane, problem i'm having is that if place the textarea under any of the textfields they get resized to the size of the textarea. I need a way to make the textarea span multiple columns of the grid without affecting the other controls. this is how I am adding the controls:

```
grid.setRowIndex(lblDesc, 3);
grid.setColumnIndex(lblDesc, 2);
grid.setRowIndex(tfDesc, 4);
grid.setColumnIndex(tfDesc,2);    
grid.getChildren().addAll(lblDesc, tfDesc);
```

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend 
root.add(element, col, row, colSpan, rowSpan)

Where root

```
GridPane root = new GridPane();
root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
root.setHgap(10);
root.setVgap(10);
root.setPadding(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50));

//Add each element to the GridPane
//.add(element, column, row ,column span, row span)  span must be >0

//row 0
root.add(sourceDirLabel, 0, 0, 2, 1);

//row1
root.add(sourceDirText,0, 1, 3, 1);
root.add(sourceDirBtn, 3, 1);

//row 2
root.add(outputDirLabel, 0, 2, 2, 1);

//row3
root.add(outputDirText,0, 3, 3, 1);
root.add(outputDirBtn, 3, 3);

//row4
root.add(runBtn, 0 , 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Didn't know about `rowSpan` and `colSpan` parameters. I guess that's the problem with method overloading? Not sure.

Again, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the API and tried one of the methods which support spanning columns?

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html

Comment: Thanks, I looked at it but but can't seem to access it through ColumnContraint? where is this located?

Comment: Use the methods of GridPane, e.g.: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add%28javafx.scene.Node,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setColumnSpan%28javafx.scene.Node,%20java.lang.Integer%29
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setConstraints%28javafx.scene.Node,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

There are more...

Comment: Puce, Thanks Much Got it now.